# sql insert monthly records (rows) from a single yearly annual

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, split

I have a table that stores a yearly budget for a single employee by product type such as below. Is it possible to have sql split the annual sums into another table by monthly numbers by product type ?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain (and show) what you expect as output in your question, that would help a lot

Comment: Show use bigger part of the picture and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question but you may refer to [INSERT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: my bad, my question was not very clear. I am trying to split a single record (annual sum) into 12 with correct subtotals. I have about 100 annual records which i need to manipulate and insert into another table with correct subtotals for each month for each employee and each product type. 100 (emp) x 12 (months) x 5 (product types) = 6000 inserts which would be very manual task.